# Convert Instant to microseconds from Epoch time

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, epoch, java-time

In `Instant` there are methods:

- [`toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) which *converts this instant to the number of milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z*
- [`getEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#getEpochSecond--) which *gets the number of seconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z*.

Both of these methods lose precision, e.g. in `toEpochMilli` JavaDoc I see:

> If this instant has greater than millisecond precision, then the conversion
>    drop any excess precision information as though the amount in nanoseconds
>    was subject to integer division by one million.

I don't see corresponding methods to obtain more precise timestamp. **How can I get number of micros or nanos from epoch in Java 8?**

Comment: For micros, there is an open request at https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196003

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As part of java.time, there are units under java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit that are useful for getting the difference between two points in time as a number in nearly any unit you please.
e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.now())
```

gives the microseconds since epoch for that Instant as a long.

Comment: Please, be aware that there are some open related issues like [JDK-8199095](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8199095) that might lead to "java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow". 
For example, on _OpenJDK (build 1.8.0_362-b08)_
`ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.parse("2262-04-10T23:59:59.999999Z"))` returns _9223286399999999_, however, `ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(Instant.EPOCH, Instant.parse("2262-04-10T23:59:59.999999Z"))` fails with `java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow`

Answer (score 31):

Use `getNano()` together with `getEpochSeconds()`.

```
int getNano()
```

> Gets the number of nanoseconds, later along the time-line, from the start of the second.
>   The nanosecond-of-second value measures the total number of nanoseconds from the second returned by `getEpochSecond`.

Convert to desired unit with `TimeUnit`, as the comment suggested:

```
Instant inst = Instant.now();
// Nano seconds since epoch, may overflow
long nanos = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(inst.getEpochSecond()) + inst.getNano();
// Microseconds since epoch, may overflow
long micros = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(inst.getEpochSecond()) + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(inst.getNano());
```

You can also find out when they overflow:

```
// 2262-04-11T23:47:16.854775807Z
Instant.ofEpochSecond(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE), 
                      Long.MAX_VALUE % TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
// +294247-01-10T04:00:54.775807Z
Instant.ofEpochSecond(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE), 
                      TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos(Long.MAX_VALUE % TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(1)))
```

Comment: Good answer. In addition to `getNano()` I suggest you use `TimeUnit` for the conversions involved, and you decide whether you need overflow detection. On one hand the microseconds of `Instant.MIN` and `Instant.MAX` will not fit into a `long`, on the other hand a `long` will suffice for `Instant`s pretty far in the past or the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try Google Guava: Instants.toEpochMicros(instant)

Comment: There is no such Guava class called `Instants`...